# How to find the kth leaf in an avl tree

Tags: c, algorithm, avl-tree

i want to solve this by adding a leaf field to my avl tree node to represent leafs below node the leaf field would tell how many leaves are below each node (n->leaves =n->left->leaves + n->right->leaves ) and modify during inserting and deletion. With this, I can move through faster ex if I am looking for 100th leaf and the left subtree has 90 leaves I can directly move to right subtree changing time complexity to O(logn) rather than O(n)

```c
typedef struct tr_n_t { 
//int leaf
    key_t key;
    struct tr_n_t *left;
    struct tr_n_t *right;
    int height; 
} tree_node_t;
```

Comment: You don't need a "is a leaf" field for your nodes. A leaf is a node with no children, i.e. where the `left` and `right` pointers are both `NULL`.

Comment: With that said, what is your real question? You seem to have three questions or problems in this question ("[h]ow to find the kth leaf in an avl tree", "[I] want to add a leaf field", "assign 1 to leafs"). Which one is you really asking about? Please ask one question per post. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

A node is a leaf if it has no child nodes. In OP's case, if (and only if) both the `left` and `right` members of a node are `NULL`, then the node is a leaf node.

Since OP's `tree_node_t` type has no pointer to the parent node, a recursive function can be used to perform an in-order traversal. The in-order traversal is being used to find the *k*th leaf node. A counter can be used to keep track of how many leaf nodes have been encountered so far. When this counter reaches the desired value `k`, the desired leaf node has been found so the function can return a pointer to the desired node, otherwise it should return 0.

```
// recursive helper function
static tree_node_t *find_leaf_k_internal(tree_node_t *node, unsigned int *count, unsigned int k)
{
    tree_node_t *kth;

    if (!node)
        return NULL; // not a node

    if (!node->left && !node->right) {
        // node is a leaf
        if (*count == k)
            return node; // node is the kth leaf

        (*count)++; // increment leaf counter
        return NULL; // not the kth leaf
    }

    // node is not a leaf
    // perform in-order traversal down the left sub-tree
    kth = find_leaf_k_internal(node->left, count, k);
    if (kth)
        return kth; // return found kth leaf node
    // kth leaf node not found yet
    // perform in-order traversal down the right sub-tree
    return find_leaf_k_internal(node->right, count, k);
}

// find kth in-order leaf node of tree counting from 0.
// returns pointer to kth leaf node, or NULL if tree contains fewer than k+1 leaf nodes.
tree_node_t *find_leaf_k(tree_node_t *root, unsigned int k)
{
    unsigned int count = 0; // in-order running count of leaf nodes

    return find_leaf_k_internal(root, &count, k);
}
```